# Images in Windows Mobile 6.5.3-style menus

Tags: windows-mobile

In Windows Mobile 6.5.3, the bottom menus come in two styles - new, touch-friendly style with rounded black buttons, and old style. In my experience, to enable the new style, the menu has to have only one or two items, and both should be text (I_IMAGENONE); if you place an image button there, the menu reverts to old style.

However, the Pocket IE in WinMo 6.5.3 has a new style menu with images - back button for example. Question - how do they do that? I could not find any relevant samples.

Native code, C++, Win32 API. Please no managed/CLR examples.

Answer (score 0):

According to CE Remote Spy it is a 64x64 `Button` class object with the style 0x5000000B = BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD.

It is the child of a 484x76 `Worker` object with the style 0x40800000

It does not appear to be the child of any menu. I think they just created a `Button` and stuck it where they wanted on the `Worker` window. It looks pretty because it's owner draw.

This example demonstrates the use of the BS_OWNERDRAW style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa454895.aspx

-PaulH

Comment: Good find... Can you check other, text-based new style command bar buttons - what are those? One doesn't normally work on that low a level with the bottom menu; SHCreateMenuBar() and SHMENUBAR resources is how it's normally done.

Comment: Found it. I don't think it's the button in Command Bar - the screen coordinates (on the QVGA emulator) are (1,21)-(22,53). That's near the screen top, not in the bottom.